# Attempting to create JUnit build configuration results in the error "JUnit not found in module" (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I'm learning JUnit in Intellij, and I'm a bit unfamiliar with the IDE and rusty with Java. I was able to (seemingly) install JUnit through Maven without a hitch (imports work and everything), but I'm coming up with weird errors when I try to make a build configuration. When I try to specify the test class in the JUnit build config template, I get this error:

[image: Can't browse TestCase inheritors: JUnit not found in module]

This doesn't make any sense, because not only are all the required .jars in my classpath, they're even copied to the `lib` folder directly in the module, rather than "linked" to.

[image: All JUnit .jars in the lib folder. Using JUnit 5.2]

I've seen lots of questions about how to install JUnit or use Maven, but I've been able to do that just fine. I haven't seen any about this particular problem, in this IDE.

(Oh, and just in case, here's the code I'm using. It probably won't be relevant to the problem, and it's rather nonsensical, but I figured I might as well include it)

```
public class ThingDoer {

    private int foo;
    private int bar;

    public int doThing(int input) {
        bar = input;
        return (foo * foo);
    }

    public int doOtherThing(int input) {
        foo = input;
        return (bar * bar);
    }

}
```

.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.ValueSource;

public class ThingDoerTests {

    @Test
    void testDoThing() {

        ThingDoer d = new ThingDoer();
        int a = d.doThing(10);
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, a);

    }


    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(ints = {9, 4, 54, 6})
    void testDoOtherThing(int input) {

        ThingDoer d = new ThingDoer();
        Assertions.assertTrue(d.doOtherThing(input) > -100);

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't you need to annotate your test class with  jUnit annotations?

Comment: @Ivan According to the [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests), you don't need to annotate tests, only methods, which I already have done.

Comment: Have you tried to specify test class name?

Answer (score 1):

Your project is configured correctly, but unfortunately the message shown by IntelliJ IDEA is confusing. The way of creating test configurations by pressing the ... button in the Class field works only for JUnit 3 tests, and the message actually means "JUnit 3 not found". There's an [open issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198059) regarding this problem in the IntelliJ issue tracker.

To run your test, you can simply right-click your test class or test method and select the "Run" or "Debug" option from the context menu.

Comment: I couldn't see any "Run" options when I clicked on anything, but switching to JUnit 4 worked. Good enough for now, I guess.

Comment: Which IntelliJ IDEA version are you using? JUnit 5 is only supported in fairly recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio add this line into `build.gradle` (app):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```